# HTML5 tr with radio row selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From the code below, I can't get the `input[radio]` to check the selected row in the table. The code below is using **HTML5** and **JQuery 1.10.2**.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            input[type="radio"] {
                margin: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />
        <script>            
            $(function() {
                $("#table_list tr").click(function() {
                    $(this).find("td input:radio").prop("checked", true);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table_list">
            <thead>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>              
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="record"/></th>
                    <td>Sample1</td>
                    <td>sample_1@sample.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="radio" name="record"/></th>
                    <td>Sample1</td>
                    <td>sample_1@sample.com</td>                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle ? Firsly, you need a value to your radio in order to evaluate them later.

Comment: Fix your markup and it will work (you have `<td></th>` and other `<th>` tags inside of the `<tbody>`, also your `<thead>` doesn't have a `<tr>`)

Comment: html fixed  here http://jsbin.com/adesux/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first input is in a `td` and the second is in a `th`. You'll have to remove the `td` from your input selector: [working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hnaej)

```
$(function() {
    $("#table_list tr").click(function() {
        $(this).find("input:radio").prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

The attached javascript will work for both.. Another option is to just change the `th` to a `td` and keep your selector the way it was.

Note: you have a few more markup issues as people mentioned in the comments. (forgot `tr` in `thead`)

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsbin.com/atosaq/4/edit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#table_list tr').on("click",function(){
$(this).find('input[type=radio]').prop("checked", true);
  });
});
```